# Javascript JSON parse a php base64(file_get_contents($file)) response

Tags: javascript, php, json, file, parsing

I have PHP that works fine but I cannot `JSON.parse` a response that contains a `base64(file_get_contents($file))` in my front-end JavaScript.

I am saving a JSON string in a MySQL table field. That string also contains the content of a file, e.g.

```js
{
  "LINK_DOC": "'861273_561004263963156_135605390_o.jpg'",
  "BD_MIME": "'jpg'",
  "RHID": "546456",
  "NOME": "54",
  "NOME_REDZ": null,
  "BD_DOC": "\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD\/\/gAEKgD\/4gv4SUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAvoAAAAAAIAAABtbnRyUkd .............",
  "DSP_NACIONALIDADE": null,
  "DSP_PAIS_RESIDENCIA": null,
  "DSP_PAIS_CORRESPONDENCIA": null
}
```

`BD_DOC` is the bas64-encoded file data.

How can I get the file back out in my front-end?

Answer (score 0):

Output of an image, output of a file on a jump on the same principle

```
$str = '{
  "LINK_DOC": "861273_561004263963156_135605390_o.jpeg",
  "BD_MIME": "jpeg",
  "RHID": "546456",
  "NOME": "54",
  "NOME_REDZ": null,
  "BD_DOC": "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",
  "DSP_NACIONALIDADE": null,
  "DSP_PAIS_RESIDENCIA": null,
  "DSP_PAIS_CORRESPONDENCIA": null
}';

$dec = json_decode($str,true);
```

html

```
<img style='display:block; width:100px;height:100px;' id='base64image' src='data:image\/<?= $dec['BD_MIME']?>;base64, <?= $dec['BD_DOC']?>'>
```